# Arbitrary length inputs for CNNs in sequential learning

Tags: conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, sequential

In [An Empirical Evaluation of Generic Convolutional and Recurrent Networks for Sequence Modeling](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.01271.pdf), the authors state that **TCN networks**, a specific type of 1D CNNs applied to sequential data, "can also take in inputs of arbitrary lengths by sliding the 1D convolutional kernels", just like Recurrent Nets. I am asking myself how this can be done.

For an RNN, it is straight-forward that the same function would be applied as often as is the input length. However, for CNNs (or any feed-forward NN in general), one must prespecify the number of input neurons. So the only way I can see TCNs dealing with arbitrary length inputs is by specifying a *fixed* length input neuron space and then adding zero padding to the arbitrary length inputs.

Am I correct in my understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a fully convolutional neural network, there is no reason to have a fully specified input shape. You definitely need a fixed rank, and the last dimension probably should be the same but otherwise, you can definitely specify an input shape which in `tensorflow` would look like `Input((None, 10))` in the case of 1D-CNNs.

Indeed the shape of the convolution kernel doesn't depend on the length of the input in the temporal dimension (it can depend on the last dimension though typically in convolutional neural networks), and you can apply it to any input with the same rank (and same last dimension).

For example let's say that you are applying only a single 1D convolution, with a kernel that's doing the sum of 2 neighbouring elements (`kernel = (1, 1)`). This operation could be applied to any input length given it's always 1D.

However, when being confronted with a sequence-to-label task and requiring further operations in the stack such as a fully-connected layer, the inputs must be of fixed length (or must be made so through zero padding).

Comment: Thank you, Zaccharie, for this answer! I fully agree with your explanation for one 1D-convolution operation and fully-convolutional NNs. However, in most cases in sequential learning tasks, we typically predict some label, say, the next word in a sentence and thus require a fully-connected layer (or some other dimension dependent operation) after the convolution operations. For such practical cases, would you agree that we then require to prespecify the number of input neurons, because otherwise, some of these fully-connected neurons might not be used (and I wouldn't know how to implement).

Comment: I think that in the case of sequence-to-label learning if you want to use convolutions, you would do as showed in the figure 1 of the article you linked, that is apply several layers of a-trous they call it dilated), causal or not, convolutions.
If you need to use a dense (fully-connected) layer, then you definitely need a fixed input size and therefore some zero-padding (not to be confused with the zero-padding they use in the article which is to perform the convolutions keeping the dimension of the sequence similar at every step).

Comment: Awesome, thank you! :-) I think this solves it. Anyone confirming this answer - not just from a practical (think DL library), but theoretical/conceptual point of view - is very welcomed!